# hive insert into structure data type using a query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-streaming

I have a use case where I have a table a. I want to select data from it, group by come fields, do some aggregations and insert the result into another hive table b having one of the column as a struct. I am facing some difficulty with it. Can some one please help and tell me whats wrong with my queries.

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a (
            date string,
            acct string,
            media string,
             id1 string,
            val INT
    ) PARTITIONED BY (day STRING)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 'folder1/folder2/';

    ALTER TABLE a ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (day='{DATE}') LOCATION 'folder1/folder2/Date={DATE}';


    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b (
            date string,
            acct string,
            media string,
            st1 STRUCT<id1:STRING, val:INT>
    ) PARTITIONED BY (day STRING)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 'path/';

    FROM a
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE b  PARTITION (day='{DATE}')
    SELECT  date,acct,media,named_struct('id1',id1,'val',sum(val))
    WHERE day='{DATE}' and media is not null and acct is not null and  NOT (id1 = "0" )
    GROUP BY date,acct,media,id1;
```

Error I got :

```
 SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 3:31 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''2015-07-16'': Cannot convert column 4 from struct<id1:string,val:bigint> to struct<id1:string,val:int>.
```

Comment: error I got :      SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 3:31 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''2015-07-16'': Cannot convert column 4 from struct<id1:string,val:bigint> to struct<id1:string,val:int>.

Answer (score 1):

Sum return a BIGINT, not an INT. So Declare

```
st1 STRUCT<id1:STRING, val:BIGINT>
```

instead of

```
st1 STRUCT<id1:STRING, val:INT>
```